# How do I set up to run batch jobs based on priority?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have looked through documentation as well as made numerous Google attempts to learn, but so far I've come up empty-handed:

1)  Is there a settable parameter that would allow me to achieve the following?  If there is, how do I configure it?

I would like to set up batch jobs so that in addition to the "normal" priority, I can have the option to run "high" priority jobs that would bump others in line.  Among the "normal" priority jobs, FIFO is fine.  I'd like to have persistent records of jobs that were submitted and their status, preferably with automatic retries of failures.

I am working with Spring-Batch 3.0.3 in particular and Spring 4.0.6 in general.  I'm submitting jobs from a webservice on a JBoss AS 7.1.1 server.

2) If there isn't an out-of the box implementation, could I write something (a taskExecutor?) to achieve this goal?  And how might I do it?

I got the suggested ThreadPoolExecutor to work, but the Job class is still intractable because I can't find where to specify the class of a job.  (For a number of reasons, I'm doing the configurations in jXML, rather than programmatically with annotations.) No matter what I do, the deployment always proceeds with org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob and then can't convert to a different job class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ExecutorService with a PriorityBlockingQueue to handle this, something like:

```
int maxThreads = 4;
ExecutorService pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, maxThreads, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

Then, for as many jobs as you have:

```
Job job = new Job(desiredPriority);
pool.execute(job);
```

These will get ordered by the PriorityBlockingQueue based on the priority you passed in to them.

Your Job class will implement Runnable and Comparable:

```
public class Job implements Runnable, Comparable<Job> {
    private final int priority;

    public Job(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Job o) {
        // enforces descending order (but this is up to you)
        if (this.priority > o.priority) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.priority < o.priority) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do whatever needs to happen on a thread
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was more-or-less what I was thinking of, but I didn't realize that I could build the PriorityBlockingQueue into the executor.    So far I'm using org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, primarily because it was mentioned in the Spring Batch documentation.

Comment: I guess my only concern at this point is whether java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor will "play well with others."  I'm adding to a rather sizeable application, and I'm skittish about the integration.  My other issue, I've realized, is that I was trying to make the wrong class Comparable.  (Now, if I could just figure out the comment editor, I'd be golden.)

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor is pretty commonly used.  Just be aware that PriorityBlockingQueue is unbounded, so if your Runnable is long-running with extremely large objects, you may want a semaphore to control how many you queue up.

Comment: Still looking for a fix.  I may have to write a Job class from scratch.  Extending it from org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob results in errors:    "load() exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob] to required type [com.company.PriorityJob] for property 'sixtySecondJob': no matching editors or conversion strategy found."   I even tried extending from FlowJob, but of course the superclass couldn't find its way to the class.

Comment: @lepome sorry I'm not more familiar with Spring internals.  Looks like they have their own job / state machine, modifications may need to be done within those limitations.  I'll read more.